# mvvmFX Throws Incompatible Type in ViewTuple for Implemented ViewModel

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, mvvmfx

I've created a sample project as shown in [getting started documentation of mvvmFX](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/wiki/Getting-Started-HelloWorld-%28english%29). My `MainViewModel` implements `de.saxsys.mvvmfx.ViewModel` as intended. The content is the same as in documentation except the class name.

Oddly, `ViewTuple` in the `start` method doesn't accept `MainViewModel` as compatible.

```
Error:(28, 102) java: incompatible types: de.saxsys.mvvmfx.ViewTuple<com.erayerdin.imageviewer.views.MainView,de.saxsys.mvvmfx.ViewModel> cannot be converted to de.saxsys.mvvmfx.ViewTuple<com.erayerdin.imageviewer.views.MainView,com.erayerdin.imageviewer.viewmodels.MainViewModel>
```

So, why `MainViewModel` implementing `de.saxsys.mvvmfx.ViewModel` is incompatible for `ViewTuple`?

---

## Code

### `App.java`

```
package com.erayerdin.imageviewer;

import com.erayerdin.imageviewer.viewmodels.MainViewModel;
import com.erayerdin.imageviewer.views.MainView;
import de.saxsys.mvvmfx.FluentViewLoader;
import de.saxsys.mvvmfx.ViewTuple;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class App extends Application {
    public static List<String> PARAMS;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Reian ImageViewer");

        ViewTuple<MainView, MainViewModel> viewTuple = FluentViewLoader.fxmlView(MainView.class).load();
        Parent root = viewTuple.getView();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

### `MainView.java`

```
package com.erayerdin.imageviewer.views;

import com.erayerdin.imageviewer.viewmodels.MainViewModel;
import de.saxsys.mvvmfx.FxmlView;
import de.saxsys.mvvmfx.InjectViewModel;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainView implements FxmlView<MainViewModel>, Initializable {
    @FXML private Label helloLabel;

    @InjectViewModel
    MainViewModel controller;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        helloLabel.textProperty().bind(controller.helloMessageProperty());
    }
}
```

### `MainViewModel.java`

```
package com.erayerdin.imageviewer.viewmodels;

import de.saxsys.mvvmfx.ViewModel;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class MainViewModel implements ViewModel {
    private StringProperty helloMessage = new SimpleStringProperty("Hello World!");

    public String getHelloMessage() {
        return helloMessage.get();
    }

    public StringProperty helloMessageProperty() {
        return helloMessage;
    }

    public void setHelloMessage(String helloMessage) {
        this.helloMessage.set(helloMessage);
    }
}
```

---

## Environment

- Java 1.8.0_144
- JavaFX 8.0.141
- mvvmFX 1.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is most likely due to a wrong Java version. Even though you are using Java 8 I assume that your IDE/Build system is configured with an older Java version.

The type inference that is used in the `FluentViewLoader` wasn't possible in previous java versions.

I've tested your classes with a standard maven project and got the same error because maven by default uses Java 1.5 (as far as I know). Then I changed the maven settings so that the compiler uses version 1.8 as source and target version like this:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

With this settings it worked as expected.